# jQuery Modify Sticky Plugin to add another class

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the below plugin for a sticky header on my website and I would like to add another class to a div `$('.logo').addClass('whatever-class');` When the is-sticky class is activated and when its not it removes that class.

Would the best way be to add a secondary `ClassName`?

**Code:**

```
(function($) {
  var defaults = {
      topSpacing: 0,
      bottomSpacing: 0,
      className: 'is-sticky',
      wrapperClassName: 'sticky-wrapper',
      center: false,
      getWidthFrom: ''
    },
    $window = $(window),
    $document = $(document),
    sticked = [],
    windowHeight = $window.height(),
    scroller = function() {
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        documentHeight = $document.height(),
        dwh = documentHeight - windowHeight,
        extra = (scrollTop > dwh) ? dwh - scrollTop : 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < sticked.length; i++) {
            var s = sticked[i],
            //elementTop = s.stickyWrapper.offset().top,
            elementTop = jQuery('#sticket-scroll-header-point').offset().top,
            //etse = elementTop - s.topSpacing - extra;
            etse = elementTop + 250;

            if (scrollTop <= etse) {
                if (s.currentTop !== null) {
                    s.stickyElement
                        .css('position', '')
                        .css('top', '');
                    s.stickyElement.parent().removeClass(s.className);
                    s.currentTop = null;
                    s.stickyElement.removeClass('fadeInDown');
                    //$('#header.header_v2').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': 0});
                    //$('#header.header_v1').css({'position': 'relative'});
                }
            }
            else {
              var newTop = documentHeight - s.stickyElement.outerHeight()
                - s.topSpacing - s.bottomSpacing - scrollTop - extra;
              if (newTop < 0) {
                newTop = newTop + s.topSpacing;
              } else {
                newTop = s.topSpacing;
              }

              if (s.currentTop != newTop) {
                s.stickyElement.parent().css('height', s.stickyElement.outerHeight());
                s.stickyElement
                  .css('position', 'fixed')
                  .css('top', newTop)
                  .css('max-width', s.stickyElement.parent().width());
                //$('#header.header_v2').css('position', 'fixed');
                if (typeof s.getWidthFrom !== 'undefined') {
                  s.stickyElement.css('width', $(s.getWidthFrom).width());
                }
                s.stickyElement.addClass('fadeInDown');
                s.stickyElement.parent().addClass(s.className);
                s.currentTop = newTop;
                //$('#header.header_v1, #header.header_v2').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': -50});
              }
            }
      }
    },
    resizer = function() {
      windowHeight = $window.height();
    },
    methods = {
      init: function(options) {
        var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
          var stickyElement = $(this);

          var stickyId = stickyElement.attr('id');
          var wrapper = $('<div></div>')
            .attr('id', stickyId + '-sticky-wrapper')
            .addClass(o.wrapperClassName);
          stickyElement.wrapAll(wrapper);

          if (o.center) {
            stickyElement.parent().css({width:stickyElement.outerWidth(),marginLeft:"auto",marginRight:"auto"});
          }

          if (stickyElement.css("float") == "right") {
            stickyElement.css({"float":"none"}).parent().css({"float":"right"});
          }

          var stickyWrapper = stickyElement.parent();
          //stickyWrapper.css('height', stickyElement.outerHeight()); //thandhoi
          sticked.push({
            topSpacing: o.topSpacing,
            bottomSpacing: o.bottomSpacing,
            stickyElement: stickyElement,
            currentTop: null,
            stickyWrapper: stickyWrapper,
            className: o.className,
            getWidthFrom: o.getWidthFrom
          });
        });
      },
      update: scroller
    };

  // should be more efficient than using $window.scroll(scroller) and $window.resize(resizer):
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scroller, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizer, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onscroll', scroller);
    window.attachEvent('onresize', resizer);
  }

  $.fn.sticky = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.sticky');
    }
  };
  $(function() {
    setTimeout(scroller, 0);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class that is added, is taken from the *options* that you pass to the extension when configuring it.

In the options you can specify a `wrapperClassName`. If you don't, it defaults to `'sticky-wrapper'`.

In that property you can even specify multiple classes, separated by a space. The extension uses [`$.addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add the class, and that method accepts one or more space separated classes, so it's perfectly fine to pass `{wrapperClassName: 'sticky-wrapper yourownclass'}` as the options.

Comment: But I want to attack a completely different div then the one it sets first - note my .addClass

Comment: Correct :) different div class pair when is-sticky is present

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see an easy way to do that without actually changing the extension's code, which is usually not a good idea, since you would loose the customization if you update the plugin. Where is the logo in  the HTML relative to the div that is stickied? Is it inside it? What is the reason you want this? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: I don't mind changing the plugin as its in my child theme of my wordpress site and is not related to any "plugin" its just script.  I have a logo that is resized to remove spacing on the main site so the logo is half cut off on the sticky bar and because of this I want to add another class to remove the "non sticky" css