# jQuery Removing a class

Tags: jquery, css

I can successfully add the `whatever-class` to the `.logo` div when `is-sticky` is found however I cannot seem to remove it when its removed back to its `sticky-wrapper` state why?.

**Code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  if( $('#header-sticky-wrapper').hasClass('.is-sticky') ){
     $('.logo').addClass('whatever-class');
  }

  if( $('#header-sticky-wrapper').hasClass('sticky-wrapper')) {
    $('.logo').removeClass('whatever-class');
  }
}
```

**Plugin Code:**

```
  (function($) {
      var defaults = {
          topSpacing: 0,
          bottomSpacing: 0,
          className: 'is-sticky',
          wrapperClassName: 'sticky-wrapper',
          center: false,
          getWidthFrom: ''
        },
        $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document),
        sticked = [],
        windowHeight = $window.height(),
        scroller = function() {
            var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
            documentHeight = $document.height(),
            dwh = documentHeight - windowHeight,
            extra = (scrollTop > dwh) ? dwh - scrollTop : 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < sticked.length; i++) {
                var s = sticked[i],
                //elementTop = s.stickyWrapper.offset().top,
                elementTop = jQuery('#sticket-scroll-header-point').offset().top,
                //etse = elementTop - s.topSpacing - extra;
                etse = elementTop + 250;

                if (scrollTop <= etse) {
                    if (s.currentTop !== null) {
                        s.stickyElement
                            .css('position', '')
                            .css('top', '');
                        s.stickyElement.parent().removeClass(s.className);
                        s.currentTop = null;
                        s.stickyElement.removeClass('fadeInDown');
                        //$('#header.header_v2').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': 0});
                        //$('#header.header_v1').css({'position': 'relative'});
                    }
                }
                else {
                  var newTop = documentHeight - s.stickyElement.outerHeight()
                    - s.topSpacing - s.bottomSpacing - scrollTop - extra;
                  if (newTop < 0) {
                    newTop = newTop + s.topSpacing;
                  } else {
                    newTop = s.topSpacing;
                  }

                  if (s.currentTop != newTop) {
                    s.stickyElement.parent().css('height', s.stickyElement.outerHeight());
                    s.stickyElement
                      .css('position', 'fixed')
                      .css('top', newTop)
                      .css('max-width', s.stickyElement.parent().width());
                    //$('#header.header_v2').css('position', 'fixed');
                    if (typeof s.getWidthFrom !== 'undefined') {
                      s.stickyElement.css('width', $(s.getWidthFrom).width());
                    }
                    s.stickyElement.addClass('fadeInDown');
                    s.stickyElement.parent().addClass(s.className);
                    s.currentTop = newTop;
                    //$('#header.header_v1, #header.header_v2').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': -50});
                  }
                }
          }
        },
        resizer = function() {
          windowHeight = $window.height();
        },
        methods = {
          init: function(options) {
            var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function() {
              var stickyElement = $(this);

              var stickyId = stickyElement.attr('id');
              var wrapper = $('<div></div>')
                .attr('id', stickyId + '-sticky-wrapper')
                .addClass(o.wrapperClassName);
              stickyElement.wrapAll(wrapper);

              if (o.center) {
                stickyElement.parent().css({width:stickyElement.outerWidth(),marginLeft:"auto",marginRight:"auto"});
              }

              if (stickyElement.css("float") == "right") {
                stickyElement.css({"float":"none"}).parent().css({"float":"right"});
              }

              var stickyWrapper = stickyElement.parent();
              //stickyWrapper.css('height', stickyElement.outerHeight()); //thandhoi
              sticked.push({
                topSpacing: o.topSpacing,
                bottomSpacing: o.bottomSpacing,
                stickyElement: stickyElement,
                currentTop: null,
                stickyWrapper: stickyWrapper,
                className: o.className,
                getWidthFrom: o.getWidthFrom
              });
            });
          },
          update: scroller
        };

      // should be more efficient than using $window.scroll(scroller) and $window.resize(resizer):
      if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scroller, false);
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizer, false);
      } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onscroll', scroller);
        window.attachEvent('onresize', resizer);
      }

      $.fn.sticky = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
          return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method ) {
          return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
          $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.sticky');
        }
      };
      $(function() {
        setTimeout(scroller, 0);
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please don't use tabs, if you do, at least make sure your code aligns

Comment: There should not be the `.` in `hasClass('.is-sticky')`.

Comment: should the `hasClass` condition be ``.hasClass('is-sticky')``, or is your class named `.is-sticky` ?

Comment: You have to show more code, where is the code that is setting/unsetting the `is-sticky` and `sticky-wrapper` classes?

Comment: @Azim And it's weird that the OP seems to be saying that that part of the code is working ;)

Comment: @JuanMendes That sections fine and works its the remove statement thats not

Comment: Your code is just running when the page is loaded, not after the element changes state. It should probably be in an event handler of some kind.

Comment: Yep, this is very weird. @JuanMendes

Comment: @Barmar Can you do an example

Comment: @JuanMendes full plugin is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300361/jquery-modify-sticky-plugin-to-add-another-class

Comment: @JessMcKenzie As I've mentioned before, your question doesn't show all the code. You have to show the code that is adding and removing `is-sticky` and `sticky-wrapper`. Don't link to a bunch of code, add the relevant code here

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Something like `$(".some-class").click(function() { if (...) { $('.logo').removeClass('whatever-class'); } });`

Comment: @JuanMendes The sticky-wrapper is just the class and the `is-sticky` is added by the code in the other question so its not a "bunch of code"

Comment: Have you verified that the if-statement actually runs? Try adding a `console.log()` in there to verify

Comment: @JessMcKenzie It is a bunch of code when you consider that for optimal questions, you're supposed to trim your code so that you can reproduce the problem and not have any extra code left (as I did in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing that is going to call your code automatically whenever `$('#header-sticky-wrapper')` changes its `class` property. You have to manually call it whenever you modify it.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(updateClasses);

    function updateClasses(){
        if( $('#header-sticky-wrapper').hasClass('is-sticky') ){
            $('.logo').addClass('whatever-class');
        }

        if( $('#header-sticky-wrapper').hasClass('sticky-wrapper')) {
            $('.logo').removeClass('whatever-class');
        }
    }

    window.onscroll = function() {
        var wrapper = $('#header-sticky-wrapper');
        if (window.scrollTop > 100 ) {
            wrapper.addClass('is-sticky');
            wrapper.removeClass('sticky-wrapper');
        } else {
            wrapper.removeClass('is-sticky');
            wrapper.addClass('sticky-wrapper');
        }

        // Changed the classes, call my function that fixes the other classes
        // You'd have to call it from anywhere else you modify that node's classes
        updateClasses()
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I am using wordpress - editing theme and I am getting ` $ is not a function` Do I need to wrap it within .ready function?

Comment: WP runs jQuery in noConflict mode. Use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: Clicked,  However the above result gives me https://www.dropbox.com/s/jaafux0nszkh26u/Screenshot%202016-02-11%2008.40.37.png?dl=0 with no class on the .logo

The original state is - I am just wanting to reset the css for the logo when sticky

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4mulmh0sth4rdz/Screenshot%202016-02-11%2008.43.27.png?dl=0

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Screenshots without the backing code are, I'm sorry, useless. If you do post a link to code, be sure to point out exactly what changes you have made to make your code do what I've suggested

Comment: I have used your code above and it gives me that result

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Sigh... Hopefully you didn't use my code as is, it's just to show a point, there's no way it would do what you ultimately need. You have to adapt the code to your needs, if it doesn't work, you post the code you actually used, along with the HTML and CSS so we can see it in action